# Finding Kernel for Group and checking homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

Let function f: Z10 -> { **0, 2, 4, 6, 8**} (additive group) be defined as f(**a**)= 2**a**. How can I check if f is homomorphism? And how to compute  **5** + Ker(f) + **2** + Ker(f).

After going through some books and lecture notes I have not find anything useful. I know how to find kernel in others notations, but this one makes me very confused. Any help would be great.

So I need to have for every element to be satisfied f(a+b) = f(a) + f(b). 
f(0+2) = 2*2 = 4 = f(0) + F(2) = 0 + 4 = 4, so this one is OK!
f(2+4) = 2*6 = 12 = f(2) + f(4) = 4 + 8 = 12 OK!
f(4+6) = 20 = 8 + 12 =20 so this one also
f(6+8) = 28 = 12 + 16 = 28 so now I have homomorphism proved?

At this point I can compute Ker (f). For Kernel I take that element form set which is neutral for addition, so it is 0. Than compute   **5** + Ker(f) + **2** + Ker(f) = 7.

NB. If there was not 0 in set there is now way to take Kernel from that set!?

Comment: The Kernel of a group are the elements which will be mapped to the 0 element. What are those elements?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: To find the kernel you must first check that the map is a morphism. Right now, what you have does not even begin to make sense, because the set $\{0,2,4,6,8\}$ is not a group under the standard addition, so you need to be a lot more careful about what it is you are doing. Once you know you have a group, check whether $f(a+b) = f(a)+f(b)$ holds for all $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}_{10}$. If it does, voila! it’s a homomorphism, and then you can find the kernel the usual way: figure out what maps to the identity.

Comment: @Paul Some language barier, by o element you think neutral element? If so then Ker (f) is 0.

Comment: Yes, but first check what @Arturo Magidin has said, since that is what you have to check in the very beginning before you could say something useful about such a function

Comment: @ArturoMagidin @ Paul I have made some changes in original post, is it now correct ?

Comment: What “addition” do you have on the set $\{0,2,4,6,8\}$? It cannot be the usual addition of integers, because you can add elements of the set to get elements not in the set. If this is supposed to be a group, you need to say more than just “additive group”. Right now, it’s not a group. It’s a set with a mystery operation on it.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin this is actually a problem from one textbook, that was left for reader. With all that they have explained in chapter I found it very confusing! I thought I am missing something and it has some unusual notation.

Comment: There may be context that you aren’t passing along. But without  that context, either because the book is missing it or because you haven’t realized what that context is, then the problem, as written, is nonsense. There are some obvious ways to *insert* meaning to make it reasonable, but that meaning needs to be there.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thanks a lot professor, I thought it is something like that! This was the first one, it was separate and nothing before it  was written in this problem set, so there  is no more context, also it was copy-paste form it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $f$ maps $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$ into the *subgroup* $\{0,2,4,6,8\}$ of $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$, then, there is a very much more straightforward way to check that $f$ is an homomorphism than yours. Check this:

> For any $a$ and $b$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$ we have $f(a+b) = 2(a+b) = 2a+2b = f(a)+f(b)$.

Also, your solution is not entirely correct because you are missing cases as, for example, $f(1+2) = f(1)+f(2)$. You see?

Also, the *kernel* of $f$ is not "zero". The kernel of $f$, denoted $\ker f$, is the set of all $a \in \mathbb{Z}_{10}$ such that $f(a) = 0$, that is, $2a=0$. Of course, the elements that satisfies precisely this are $0$ and $5$, so, $\ker f = \{0,5\}$.

Now, when we write $a+H$, for $a \in \mathbb{Z}_{10}$ and $H$ a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$, $a+H$ is the set of all elements of the form $a+b$ for some $b \in H$. Then, for example,
$$7 + \ker f = 7 + \{0,5\} = \{7,12\} = \{2,7\}.$$

Can you finish this?

Comment: Yes I think I can see it! It was very strange set (every second number) so I thought I have and can to operate and check only with those given numbers, also, by mistake I forgot 5.

Answer (score 0):

So, I guess, you have $\Bbb Z_5$ there as the range.

It's straight forward to check that you have a homomorphism.

The kernel would be $\{0,5\}$.

The sum of two cosets can be gotten by adding the representatives.  So $(5+H)+(2+H)=7+H=2+H$, where $H=\operatorname{ker}f$.

Note that your notation for $\Bbb Z_5$ is a little weird.  Normally you'll see $\Bbb Z_5=\{0,1,2,3,4\}$.  Note also that $5+H=H$, since $5\in H$.

Comment: First of all thanks a lot! I have made some changes in original post, done some computation. Can you take a look at it please

Comment: Sure.  You need to check for all pairs of elements whether the homomorphism property is satisfied.  You can do it all at once, by writing $f(a+b)=2(a+b)=2a+2b=f(a)+f(b)$.  Good luck getting used to some of these new ideas.  As I said, I think you're talking about $\Bbb Z_5$, because there's only one five element group.